# Passport-Facebook authentication is not providing email or other information(undefined) for all Facebook accounts

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have tried everything but I am not able to get any other info. from fb account. I am only getting displayName and id from my facebook strategy :

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({

    clientID        : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret    : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL     : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
   // profileFeilds   : ['id','displayName','email'],
    passReqToCallback : true,
    profileFeilds   : ['id', 'email', 'gender', 'link', 'locale', 'name', 'timezone', 'updated_time', 'verified'],
 },
function( req,accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    //console.log(profile);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(profile));
    done(null,profile);

}));
```

The get part:

```
    router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));
    router.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
        passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/',
        failureRedirect : '/blogs',
        //scope:['email']
        }));
```

Output:

```
 { id: '1233755832057029',
username: undefined,
displayName: 'John Maverick',
name:
 { familyName: undefined,
  givenName: undefined,
  middleName: undefined },
gender: undefined,
profileUrl: undefined,
provider: 'facebook',
_raw: '{"name":"John Maverick","id":"1223755832057029"}',
_json: { name: 'John Maverick', id: '1223755832057029' } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));
```

To this

```
router.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : ['email'] }));
```

And change this:

```
profileFeilds
```

To this:

```
profileFields
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, was really banging my head and not able to see it was just a typo...

Comment: Nevermind ma friend , that's my life day by day hahaha